# Remove a path in $PATH in Linux OS

Tags: 18.04

My aim is to install JAVA. But I think something went wrong during the installation so I started right from the beginning. I unset the JAVA_HOME variable and am trying to remove the path `/opt/jdk-14/bin`. I tried a few things, but nothing seems to work out

`sudo grep -rl "/opt/jdk-14/bin" /etc`

I checked `~/.profile,  ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, /etc/bashrc`. But none of the files have the path `/opt/jdk-14/bin` in it.

**Updated**

I installed the java all over again. And same path is repeated twice now.

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/jdk-14/bin:/home/dell/flutter/bin:/opt/jdk-14/bin`

Comment: does this help? https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/19618/remove-a-path-from-the-path-environment-variable

Comment: Do you need to remove ``/opt/jdk-14/bin`` from $PATH or add it. I can make instructions more specific that way. Also please post current ```~/.bashrc```.

Comment: My aim is to install JAVA. But I think something went wrong during the installation so I started right from the beginning. I unset the JAVA_HOME variable and am trying to remove the path `/opt/jdk-14/bin`.

Comment: If nothing works out , as a last solution try installing silversearcher and then do `sudo ag "/opt/jdk-14/bin" /`

Comment: There are some more files to check: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables

Comment: I tried `sudo ag "/opt/jdk-14/bin" /`. while using `echo $PATH` in a new terminal, its the same.

Comment: But don't you need the path there, if you use java?

Comment: I didn't get a solution for the problem, just found a roundabout it. I installed java version 10. set the variable `JAVA_HOME` by `export JAVA_HOME=/home/dell/jdk-10` and then `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"`. Even though the path `/opt/jdk-14/bin` is still there, I was able to replace java version 14 with java version 10.

Comment: @User24601, I did use that link. I used this `rpath(){
    for path in "$@";do
        PATH="$(echo "$PATH" |sed -e "s#\(^\|:\)$(echo "$path" |sed -e 's/[^^]/$
    done
    echo "$PATH"
}

PATH="$(rpath /opt/jdk-14/bin)"` While using `echo $PATH` in a new terminal the path is back.

Comment: You have to add the script (or for shorter, the one in my answer) in a your Bash configuration file.

Comment: Don't forget to check `/etc/environment` as a location as well

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) for options where environment variables may be set. Maybe you can remove the excessive path setting there and you can ignore the rest of this answer.

Not all of the places mentioned in the linked article allow script execution. But one option is to create a file with .sh filename extension in /etc/profile.d/
and add the following script there. That way it is executed system wide when desktop session starts:

```
rpath() {
    set -- $(printf '%s\n' "$@" | sed -e 's/[^^]/[&]/g' -e 's/\^/\\^/g')
    while [ "${1+x}" ]; do
        PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -r -e 's#(^|:)'"$1"'/?(:|$)#\2#g' -e 's/^://')
        shift
    done
}
rpath '/opt/jdk-14/bin'
unset -f rpath
```

You could even give more than one argument for the `rpath` function. However, it doesn't help if you try to remove the path before it has been added in another file that is processed later.

Credits: improved from [this](https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/19618/remove-a-path-from-the-path-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0):

## To find where path is being set use:

```
sudo grep -rnw --exclude-dir={media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e "/opt/jdk-14/bin"
```

---

## To temporarily remove a path for current session

You can use `sed` to search and replace the unwanted path to nothing. First look at your current `$PATH` variable contents:

```
$ echo $PATH

/home/rick/bin:/home/rick/.local/bin:/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin::/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Assuming the path to remove is `/snap/bin:` then use:

```
$ NewPath=$(echo "$PATH" | sed 's#/snap/bin:##')
```

Now see what new path looks like:

```
$ echo $NewPath

/home/rick/bin:/home/rick/.local/bin:/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games::/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

If you like what you see the final step is to use `PATH=$NewPath`

Comment: Your replace script would not work if /snap/bin was the last one in PATH or if there was e.g /opt/snap/bin: before it in PATH.

Comment: @jarno Very true. It's not a script though that accepts parameters. It's a one liner where you plug in the values and review the output. Then change the values if `NewPath` is not what you wanted it. After it looks good then you assign it to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I referred this [java installation link](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-20-04/), on setting the JAVA_HOME variable, the other path was removed.